# Javascript if-statement vs. comparsion

Tags: javascript

Is it true that in if-statement JavaScript wrap the condition into a Boolean?

```
if(x) => if(Boolean(x))
```

Is it true that in comparison JavaScript wrap the compare elements into a Number?

```
a == b => Number(a) == Number(b)
```

Comment: MDN: Comparition Operators: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Answer (score 3):

Yes, and No.

For the first part, **yes**, that is essentially what the javascript does.

But for the latter, **no**. Not everything in JavaScript can be converted to a number. For example:

```
Number('abc') // => NaN
```

And Not-A-Numbers are not equal:

```
NaN == NaN // => false
```

So something like this:

```
Number('abc') == Number('abc') // => false!
```

But that's actually true with equality comparison.

```
'abc' == 'abc' // => true
```

**As a side note**, it's probably better to use `===` in JavaScript, which also checks the type of the values being compared:

```
0 == '0' // => true
0 === '0' // => false, because integer is not a string
```

More details about `===` can be [read over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use).

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, that's true, `x` is evaluated in a boolean context in this situation, so the equivalent of `Boolean(x)` is applied.
2. No, that's not true. It only looks that way because the [coercitive equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) `==` tries to convert `a` and `b` to the same type. `Number()` is only applied if either `a` or `b` is already a `Number`. For instance:

---

```
>>> 0x2A == 42
true   // both 'a' and 'b' are numbers.

>>> "0x2A" == 42
true   // 'a' is a string whose number coercion is equal to 'b'.

>>> "0x2A" == "42"
false  // 'a' and 'b' are different strings.
```

Comment: what if a or b are booleans? e.g. a = true

Comment: Booleans are also converted to numbers (`true == 1` and `false == 0`) if the other operand is a number.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it true that in if-statement JavaScript wrap the condition into a Boolean?

*Usually* yes.

> Is it true that in comparison JavaScript wrap the compare elements into a Number?

*Absolutely* no.

### Explanation

From [JavaScript Language Specifications](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf).

The `if` statement is defined at **§ 12.5** as:

> if ( Expression ) Statement else Statement

It says that the *Expression* will be evaluated, converted with `GetValue()` and then tested after the `ToBoolean()` conversion.

Then the **first assertion is true** (but see later), the condition for the `if` statement is evaluated like is passed as parameter to the `Boolean` function. Please recall how JavaScript handles type conversion to boolean (**§ 9.2**):

- `undefined` and `null` values are converted to `false`.
- numbers are converted to `false` if ±0 or `NaN` otherwise they're converted to `true`.
- strings are converted to `false` if empty otherwise always to `true` regardless their content.
- objects are always converted to `true`.

Because of the call to `GetValue()` strictly speaking this assertion is not *always* true, take a look to **§ 8.7.1** where the standard describes how `GetValue()` works, here can happen some *magic* conversion before `ToBoolean()` is called.

The `==` operator is defined as in **§ 11.9.3**. 
As you can see it doesn't specify that operands must be (or will be treated as) numbers, the behavior of the operator is different and regulated by a series of rules based on the type of the operands. Then your **second assertion is false**. The case they're numbers (or one of them is a number) is just a special case in the algorithm, please note that at point 4 of the algorithm it says that if one of them is a number and the other one is a string then it'll be converted with `ToNumber()`, only in this case (with all the implications that this conversion has).

It's intuitive if you think that you can compare functions, strings or numbers, not every type can be converted to a numeric value.